# Git repeated clone vs pull

Tags: git

**Use Case**:

I have MyApp that will be deployed at ClientX. I am writing a shell script to fetch that branch from my bitbucket repo

my shell script (that works fine)

```
git clone -b $BRANCH_NAME https://$USER_NAME@bitbucket.org/MyApp/ecodrone.git
```

**Question**:

Now with updates, is it better to have

1. git clone every time
2. one git-clone.sh and one git-pull.sh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have persistent storage, then re-cloning would be very inefficient (especially cloning the whole history, as you aren't using `--depth=`).

Meanwhile a pull/fetch will only receive objects which have actually changed. Use:

- `git fetch && git reset --hard "origin/$BRANCH_NAME"` to always retrieve the latest commit,
- or `git pull --ff-only` if you prefer it to fail hard if someone tried to do a history rewrite.

Don't use a plain `git pull` as it can cause a big mess in the latter case.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

2. git pull

For updating it is better to git pull or git fetch, rebase and merge if you are working with other people on the same branch (&/or files), since git pull tries to merge only if there are no merge conflicts.

Also it would be a better idea to create a new branch based on the branch you cloned so as to resolve the merge conflicts locally on your computer more easily. This is generally called a feature branch in workflow. This way once your work is done and committed, you can run git pull on the master branch (for lack of a name I'm calling the branch you cloned master), that should happen without any problems and then you can rebase feature from master and merge (use --no-ff flag if you wish to retain the feature branch log/commit history, it gets squashed into one commit otherwise) feature to master. Then push your work (master branch) upstream.

should go something like:

```bsh
git checkout -b feature
...work, stage changes & commit...
git checkout master
git pull upstream/master #or git pull origin master based on git remote urls
git checkout feature
git rebase -i upstream/master
git checkout master 
git merge --no-ff master feature
git push upstream #or git push origin
```

Also I don't understand why you'd want to clone it again, cloning is supposed to be a one time thing for git repositories